# how to give File Permissions for any file with some ID?

Tags: security, permissions

i want to buy some product in telegram and they people send me id-3.exe file to see my ID of something (https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1zDY.png) like that this photo and after that i copy and send them after that then give the file with only Permission for this id .
I want to understand how they do it and if there are similar ways you can explain to me

i want only to know how they do its and if have similar ways to do that in myself